# How can I centre an NSAttributedString, regardless of attributes?

Tags: cocoa, text, drawing

I'm looking to draw an `NSAttributedString` to a custom view and centre it vertically, regardless of the font, size, etc. The string is just a small number between 1-99.

So far, I've tried calling the `[NSAttributedString size]` method to allow me determine the height of the string as drawn. The plan was to then use the height figure to centre the string when drawing it using `drawInRect:` or `drawAtPoint:`. The problem I have, is that the height returned from the size method is larger than the glyphs that get drawn. After doing a bit of experimentation, it seems the `size:` method returns the height of the tallest possible glyphs with those attributes, including descenders, etc., rather than the height of the particular glyphs in my NSAttributedString.

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned by Joshua Nozzi in his answer, I can appreciate that the maximum height is what you'd want to use for vertical centering, since that would prevent your text from jumping around vertically as the string changed. However, in my case, I want to visually centre a number, e.g "10", often inside a circle. It's the actual height of the line "10" that I care about when doing that.

How would I get a bounding box that is tightly bound to the actual glyphs that are drawn? I think I might be getting somewhere with using Core Text and the `CTLineGetImageBounds()` function; however, it's a lot of code. If I can do it without using such verbose/low level code, that would be better.

I'm aware I could be completely barking up the wrong tree with the above method. What method would you suggest? Do I need to get into using Cocoa Text/Core Text directly, rather than using the additions to NSAttributedString?

The text system in Mac OS is so feature rich that it's a little intimidating to a beginner such as myself. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ah, that's some good detail in your update. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you definitely want the height behavior you described. Imagine if the drawn string changes from using characters that don't need that "extra" height to using characters characters that do. The drawn string would jump around vertically. Not good. *Definitely* use the height given by the text system for a specified font.

To answer your main question, drawInRect: will wrap to the width of the supplied rectangle depending on paragraph attributes. If you don't want to worry about wrapping at all, it's best to use -drawAtPoint: and compute the center manually. The vertical center is half the height of the proposed rectangle in which you're centering minus half the height of the attributed string's -size (or a regular string's -sizeWithAttributes:). The y coordinate of the NSPoint you supply to -drawAtPoint: can be computed with `NSMidY(rect) - ([attrString size].height / 2)`.

If you do care about wrapping and you already know the available width, you can use NSAttributedString's -boundingRectWithSize:options:. The size you pass in should have its width set to your available width and the height set to zero. This tells the method you want to know the needed height when wrapped to the given width. You can then use the returned rectangle as your drawing rectangle for -drawInRect: and then center *that* rectangle inside whatever target rectangle.

I hope this is clear and helpful. There isn't enough detail in your question to get more specific (ie, what are you centering *into*, if you allow wrapping, know the width but not the height, etc.).

***None of the Above***

Based on your comment and update, I think you can use -[NSBezierPath appendBezierPathWithGlyph:inFont] to get the path of an individual glyph, then -[NSBezierPath bounds].size to get its size for centering. That should give you only what's actually drawn from the individual glyph.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Problem is, if I'm using the maximum height for a glyph, rather than the height for my specific glyphs, then what I'm drawing may look a little weird, since the text won't be vertically centred as seen. As an example, in some cases, I actually want to draw a single glyph (a character from 1-5) visually centred within a circle. In that case, I (think) I really do want the height of my particular glyphs and not the height for the tallest glyph in that font/point size. I hear your point about text jumping around vertically, but that's probably not relevant to my case.

Comment: Ah. That's the kind of detail that's best to post in your original question. :-) Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry Joshua, my question could have been better. I'm a bit of a beginner so sometimes it's not obvious what's important. Thanks for the tip. That seems like it'll work if I'm drawing a number from 0-9 since it's a single glyph. Would be good if I can find a generalised solution for lines of glyphs too since in some cases I'm going to want to draw numbers higher than 9.

Comment: This is the point where you spend some time reading the API reference. Right after the NSBezierPath method I mentioned is -appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:count:inFont:, which gives you the path of a number of glyphs. The rest of the approach is the same.

Comment: I'm almost there with that technique, although the bounds include some trailing whitespace, which is a pain. My Core Text technique has some leading whitespace that I'm having trouble getting rid of. I'm sure I'll work it out with a bit more work.